# How to add widgets to container widget in ipython/jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to make VBox widget and and add a new row with text when button is clicked.

I try the following code

```
import ipywidgets as wg
from ipywidgets import Layout
from IPython.display import display

vb = wg.VBox([wg.Text('1'),wg.Text('2')])
btn = wg.Button(description = 'Add') 

def on_bttn_clicked(b):        
    vb.children=tuple(list(vb.children).append(wg.Text('3'))) 

btn.on_click(on_bttn_clicked)
display(vb, btn)

list(hb.children)
```

But the assignment "hb.children=" does not work... 
Is there a way to edit container widgets with code in the same cell?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: The line `vb.children=tuple(list(vb.children).append(wg.Text('3'))` may be where your main problem is: `list(vb.children).append(wg.Text('3')` return `None` and therefore you are passing `None` to the `tuple` constructor method. This should, in fact, throw an error. Please share that error here.

Comment: Yes @Abdou you are right. append method return None. I modified the code `def on_bttn_clicked(b):
    temp = list(vb.children)
    temp.append(wg.Text('3'))
    vb.children=temp`  It works fine now!

Comment: @StanislavPopovych great! you should answer your own question =)

Answer (score 8):

You can use a simple plus to concatenate two lists.

`vb.children=tuple(list(vb.children) + [new_button])`

So your full script will look like this:

```py
import ipywidgets as wg
from ipywidgets import Layout
from IPython.display import display

vb = wg.VBox([wg.Text('1'),wg.Text('2')])
btn = wg.Button(description = 'Add') 

def on_bttn_clicked(b):        
    vb.children=tuple(list(vb.children) + [wg.Text('3')]) 

btn.on_click(on_bttn_clicked)
display(vb, btn)

list(vb.children)
```