# Add HBox to VBox using Button after creation

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I am trying to make an input widget for a module i have made.

The input widget should have a title bar and a variable number of input lines below. I had in mind to have an add button which should add a line directly below the title line.

I have tried following this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986451/how-to-add-widgets-to-container-widget-in-ipython-jupyter) and [this issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1764) on github. But these suggestions only add a widget to the bottom of the VBox.

I have made the following dummy example.

```py
import ipywidgets as w

def add_button_clicked(b):
    #This adds new line at bottom
    #input_box.children += (line(),)
    #This is intended to add line below title but does not work
    input_box.children = (input_box.children[0], line(), input_box.children[1:])

add = w.Button(icon="plus-circle")
add.on_click(add_button_clicked)

title = w.HBox([w.Label(value=str(i)) for i in range(3)]+[add])

def line():
    delete = w.Button(icon="trash")
    return w.HBox([w.FloatText(value=i) for i in range(3)]+[delete])

input_box = w.VBox([title,line()])
display(input_box)
```

However this does not produce a new line as expected.
Unfortunately clicking the button does not throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are assigning a tuple containing two `HBox` objects and one `tuple` to `input_box.children`. You can check this by adding some "debug" lines at the start of `add_button_clicked` function:

```
print(type(input_box.children[0]))
print(type(line()))
print(type(input_box.children[1:]))
```

Solution is easy, just concatenate tuples using `+`:

```
input_box.children = (input_box.children[0], line()) + input_box.children[1:]
```